# Displaying data owned by the current logged in users

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

While creating API'S I'm using queryset on my model and trying to get only the data owned by the logged in users, but I'm getting some errors.

Console Log

```
from . import views
  File "F:\coding and stuff\finMSG\chatbot\chatbotapi\views.py", line 8, in <module>
    class queryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  File "F:\coding and stuff\finMSG\chatbot\chatbotapi\views.py", line 10, in queryViewSet
    queryset = query.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Models.py

```
# Create your models here.
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class query(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    referencetoken = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.referencetoken
```

Views.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import querySerializer, BotSocialConfigSerializer, SkillsSerializer, BotsSerializer
from .models import query, BotSocialConfig, Intents, Skills, Bots
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated


# Create your views here.
class queryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = query.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
    serializer_class = querySerializer
```

How can I get data only for user that is currently logged in.

Comment: override get_queryset method and you can get user there
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the query-set attribute and overwrite the get_queryset method

```
   def get_queryset(self):
        queryset =  query.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset
```